# IOS: problem with resize a UIImage

Tags: ios, xcode, image-resizing

I wanto to resize an UIImage and I try this code:

```
UIImage *newImage = [image1toResize _imageScaledToSize:CGSizeMake(290, 390) interpolationQuality:1];
```

but I have this warning:
warning: 'UIImage' may not respond to '-_imageScaledToSize:'

why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

_imageScaledToSize is not a UIImage function.  If this function is part of a 3rd Party library you are using then you need to make sure that you #import the right headers in your file.

Answer (score 8):

You did not ask for it but just in case you are interested in how to... Here is a very simple code to do it:

```
CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(1024, 768);  //whaterver size
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();    
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: I know this thread is a year old, but I had success with your code, with one exception... my image is as follows:
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"];

That particular image file (different variable) is used elsewhere on my display, and it is resizing in both places... do I have some reference issue somewhere? Or do I have to have another copy of the image in my files? The latter just seems awkward...

Comment: You probably have a reference issue.

Answer (score 3):

You can Resize by doiing:

```
+ (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize {
   //UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
   UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
   [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
   UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();    
   UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
   return newImage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This because `UIImage` class don't have such method. List of available `UIImage` methods you can find [there](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use these categories on `UIImage` to manipulate `UIImage` objects (to resize them or crop them, for instance):

http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/

Answer (score 0):

Best way to scale images without losing the aspect ratio (i.e. without stretching the imgage) is to use this method:

```
//to scale images without changing aspect ratio
```

+ (UIImage *)scaleImage:(UIImage *)image toSize:(CGSize)newSize {

```
float width = newSize.width;
float height = newSize.height;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);

float widthRatio = image.size.width / width;
float heightRatio = image.size.height / height;
float divisor = widthRatio > heightRatio ? widthRatio : heightRatio;

width = image.size.width / divisor;
height = image.size.height / divisor;

rect.size.width  = width;
rect.size.height = height;

//indent in case of width or height difference
float offset = (width - height) / 2;
if (offset > 0) {
    rect.origin.y = offset;
}
else {
    rect.origin.x = -offset;
}

[image drawInRect: rect];

UIImage *smallImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return smallImage;
```

}

Add this method to your Utility class so you can use it throughout your project, and access it like so:

```
xyzImageView.image = [Utility scaleImage:yourUIImage toSize:xyzImageView.frame.size];
```

This method takes care of scaling while maintaining aspect ratio.
It also adds indents to the image in case the scaled down image has more width than height (or vice versa).